# How to Print Text In Web Assembly

Tags: webassembly

Is there any way to print text onto the window directly in web assembly instead of having to pass string data into javascript, or print to the console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  WebAssembly can't directly manipulate the DOM yet.  For now you must use Javascript glue.  It is a planned [future feature](http://webassembly.org/docs/gc/) however.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to draw text with OpenGL, by using [OGLFT](http://oglft.sourceforge.net/) or similar library.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is still no, and it will remain no. It is central to the design of Wasm that it does not have any built-in functionality that depends on a given environment (because it is intended to be embeddable in many different environments) or that gives Wasm code the capability to manipulate its environment other than through explicit imports (because that would break the ability to sandbox a Wasm module).

Comment: I found a link saying that DOM manipulation is indeed planned: https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/1079.

Comment: Yes, I happen to be the champion of this proposal. But don't misinterpret it. That will still require importing functionality to *get* a reference to a DOM object, and to actually manipulate it.

Comment: So if it cannot output text to the screen what use is it? Looks like it's going to be a nightmare to debug.

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy late reply, but as another answer mentions it is basically trivial to import a js function to print instead

Comment: Trivial for a js expert maybe. The problem is that it has to rely on something else to do a "Hello World" level task. So only people with a specific need for WASM will bother learning it.

Comment: Wasm merely defines a virtual instruction set, similar to a CPU. Printing is an OS service. So Wasm has no print facility in the same way that an x86 has no print facility. That has to be provided by the embedder of a Wasm engine, and its availability depends on the ecosystem Wasm is running in (browsers are only one of many places in which Wasm is used).

Answer (score 0):

check out https://github.com/twiddlingbits/tiny-wasm-runtime

or npm install tiny-wasm-runtime

You can print from C to a <div> or <canvas> using C targeting Web Assembly.
You can also draw to a <canvas>

(i am the author of this software)

Comment: When you post answers with links to resources with which you have an affiliation, [you are expected](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) to disclose that affiliation in the post. Please [edit] your answer to include your affiliation. Otherwise your post may be deleted. Please see [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).